# Checking for gzip or plain text and reading the file without checking extensions - python

Tags: python, file-io, compression, gzip

I have files and they are exactly the same format when read but the only difference is that I'm not sure whether some of these files are `gzip`.

An example file is as such:

```
der ||| the ||| 0.3 ||| ||| 
das ||| the ||| 0.4 ||| |||  
das ||| it ||| 0.1 ||| ||| 
das ||| this ||| 0.1 ||| ||| 
die ||| the ||| 0.3 ||| |||
```

And when i read it i am currently doing this:

```
try: 
    with gzip.open(phrasetablefile, 'rb') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            # do something
except:
    with open(phrasetablefile, 'rb') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            # do something
```

**Is there other ways to do it without the ugly repeating the code?** (note that # do something is pretty long piece of code)

**Is there a way to do the following?**

```
try: 
    with gzip.open(phrasetablefile, 'rb') as fin:
except:
    with open(phrasetablefile, 'rb') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            # do something
```

Comment: Why not pull it out to a function e.g. `process`, then just have `process(fin)`? Also, at the very least, that should be `except Exception`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, words of wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning:** Untested code

Either do (as @jonrsharpe suggests):

```
def process(fin):
    for line in fin:
        pass # do something

try:
    with gzip.open(phrasetablefile, 'rb') as fin:
        process(fin)
except:
    with open(phrasetablefile, 'rb') as fin:
        process(fin)
```

or try something like this:

```
try: 
    fin = gzip.open(phrasetablefile, 'rb')
except:
    fin = open(phrasetablefile, 'rb')

for line in fin:
    pass # do something
fin.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gzip suffix you could do something like this?

```
if phrasetablefile.endswith('.gz'):
    opener = gzip.open
else:
    opener = open

with opener(phrasetablefile, 'rb') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        # do something
```